# how to handle the redux state when passing data from parent to child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

My application contains two components,

1. ListComponent(parent) which contains a list of users,
2. UserComponent(child) which displays the user info

User List Page:

```
<ListComponent 
   data={this.props.users} 
   renderItem={(item) => <UserComponent user={item} />}
/>
```

User Page:

```
render(){
    let { user, followers } = this.props;
    user = {
    ...user,
    ...followers
}
    return (
<div> 
   <span>{user.totalFollowers}</span>
   <button onClick={() => reduxHelper(user.totalFollowers + 1)}></button>
</div>)
}
```

**State To Props:**

```
mapStatetoProps = (state) => ({
  followers: state.user.followers 
})
```

**Reducer:**

```
initial_state = {
followers: {}
}
```

After Success:

```
followers: {
   totalFollowers: action.totalFollowers
}
```

I am using the redux state to hold the user list when the user(Device User) clicks on the user icon which sends the user props to UserComponent, There I am showing the user info. If the user(Device User) clicks on the follow button then updating the backend and user profile info using redux & redux-saga.

1. From the above code not able to update user data globally(Redux State)
2. Or Can I update the entire list?
3. Am I following the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to handle such generic issues.

1. From Parent component send a method as prop to child. Inside this method dispatch the action to update the store.. etc. Inside child component for ex

   `<div onClick={()=>this.props.methodFromParent(send some data if needed)}`

   inside Parent catch that method and update the store .. ex

   `<ChildComponent methodFromParent={(someData)=>this.methodFromParent(someData)}`
   ..
   Now inside the methodFromParent update the store

   `methodFromParent = ()=>{this.props.dispatch(whatever workflow u r using)}`
2. Form child component itself .. using `store.dispatch()`
   so first import store inside the child component then u can use `sotre.dispatch(someaction)`. But this approach is not good.. you should set up your project in the above-mentioned approach. And use these `store.dispatch(), store.getState()`. In case of emergency, where you dont have access to mapStateToProps, etc.